# How to return to Judaism if my family ancestors left it before my birth?

Tags: how-to, baal-teshuva

I want to return to Judaism, which my family ancestors left before my birth. How should somebody in my situation go about doing that?  What proof will I need to furnish?

I don't already have a rabbi to ask (obviously).  How should I go about finding someone who can help me?  I live in Houston, Texas.

Comment: Welcome to M.Y. James! Best of luck on your journey. To learn more about this site see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help). Or consider taking this quick [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: with your "for practical advice consult your rabbi" that is a general response of course but this OP probably doesn't have a rabbi which is why my answer suggested him one to contact who will either be able to help or redirect him to one better qualified.

Comment: James, welcome to Mi Yodeya.  We can't give personal advice, but I've made some edits to your question to try to make it a better fit for this site.  If there's anything you don't like about my edit please feel free to [edit] further.  With luck, these edits will be enough for the community to reopen the question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Isn't the top answer now obsolete? Houston is not part of the qeustion anymore or the user's profile

Comment: @DoubleAA good call.  I'll leave a comment there and ask him to generalize it; I'll also edit the OP's location back into the question (though I'm a little concerned about that).  Anybody reading this who wants to discuss, object, or propose another resolution, please bring up on meta.

Answer (score 4):

To start, get in touch with a Jewish Orthodox Rabbi and the one I have found in your area is:

Rabbi Wender, Young Israel of Houston, 7823 Ludington, Houston, Texas, 77071.

e-mail: RW@yihouston.org

phone: 713-729-0719

For others who live in a different area who have a similar issue, try to seek out an orthodox Rabbi in your vicinity. The key to knowing whether or not they are orthodox is that they will be affiliated to an orthodox establishment.

Comment: I remember him! Wow - Still there after I last saw him about 15 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

The road you are considering taking is the most beautiful road of Creation; but, it may also be the longest. Prepare yourself for this.

Having returned to Judaism myself, I personally recommend inhaling with a fiery passion from websites like:

- simpletoremember.com
- chabad.org
- aish.com
- thereisone.com

These websites gave me a lot of fuel with which to embark on the road back to Judaism. With respect, I do not recommend MiYodeya for a complete beginner.

As suggested, you will also want to reach out to local Orthodox Jewish Rabbis and fellow returnees to Judaism.

Comment: Perhaps the very subjective nature of the question and, therefore, the answers is to blame. Hence, the "on hold" status. I am happy to continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: @CashCow "isn't that what comments are for?"  [No, actually](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).  Discussions should be taken to chat.  If you disagree fundamentally with an answer, it's better to add your own (as you did).  Comments are to improve the post, e.g. to suggest a point that the author hasn't considered, to ask a question, etc.  Once the author has declined, please don't continue to discuss in comments.

Comment: I'm too busy at work to join "chat". I do not disagree with the answer enough to downvote it. I also agree Mi Yodeya isn't the place to find answers for someone like that.

Comment: You don't need to use chat if you don't want to, but that doesn't mean you can use comments for chatting.  Chat needn't be synchronous, by the way -- the room is durable, so if you and the person you're chatting with can't both be there at the same time because of work or timezones or whatever, that's fine.