# Are there any yeshiva programs (Israel or US) that begin mid-year?

Tags: product-recommendation, yeshiva-school

I was raised Reform -- with very light-handed text study and just enough Hebrew to get through my Bar Mitzvah -- and recently had a bit of an epiphany: there's nothing I find more fulfilling than studying Talmud. I'm looking to take next semester (and possibly the semester after that) off from college to study in yeshiva. However, it's obviously very last minute, and I'd need to find a program that welcomes students to begin in the middle of the year, i.e. in January. I was wondering if anyone here could guide me to schools or other resources, as I'm woefully unfamiliar with yeshiva cartography. So far, I have found the Mayanot Institute in Israel but I am looking around for others.

I'm new to this sub, as well, so I hope you'll pardon me if my question is poorly suited to it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya cloudchamber. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: See also [this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92616/11501)

Comment: Welcome Cloudchamber to MY. Although not exactly what you are asking, you may want to join a Daf Yomi group. Daf Yomi cycles through the entire Talmud in seven (or so) years and then starts over again. You learn a small portion of the Talmud daily. You may “enter” at any time.  Only orthodox synagogues tend to offer Daf Yomi study.

Comment: Can I address the elephant in the corner? If you're mother is Jewish, you're Jewish. Since Reform Judaism recognizes people with Jewish fathers (and non-Jewish mothers) as Jewish, if you're one of those people Orthodox institutions will probably not help you learn Gemara. I'm just pointing this out, I'm not trying to be confrontational.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I know a few people in Daf Yomi groups so I'll be sure to inquire. To clarify: yes, I am (halachically) Jewish, as are both of my parents, but I was raised in a household without much religious presence  -- one that put the stress, as Reform / Reconstructionist communities often do, on the "ethno-" in "ethnoreligion." So I know very little, but I'm eager to make up for lost time.

Comment: I believe that Aish Hatorah in Yerushalayim may be able to help you. Check with them.

Answer (score 9):

I believe most or all Israeli *yeshivot* targeting English-speaking *baalei tshuva* will accept people year-round. A few links to get you started:

- [Ohr Somayach](https://ohr.edu/study_in_israel/)
- [Aish HaTorah](http://www.aish.com/ai/ip/?s=footer)
- [Shapell/Darchei Noam](https://shapellsjerusalem.com/about/programs/)
- [Machon Meir](https://meirtv.com/en)

Good luck on your search !

Comment: You dont tell us your age or your standard. You will find the talmud in English but it isnt the same as in its original Aramaic. You have a long road to travel and I wish you all the best

Comment: I would like to add a few pertinent insights into the list above.  1. Ohr Somayach will help you specifically with Talmud learning - and you can start immediately with it.  2. Aish is geared to beginners, but tends to focus on proving the Torah is true, first and then with introduction to the Talmud - particularly in your case, you might find it frustrating.  Shappells might expect commitment for the year, and Machon Meir might also want a commitment in other areas.  Do your research!

Comment: I don't know if the OP stated he's no longer Reform, which may be relevant.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! Thank you. And, yes, I am hoping to learn Aramaic to remain faithful to the original text; whether this should be a preliminary step or a later one, however, is something I'm still brooding over.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add some relevant information: Since Israeli Yeshivot accept students from all over the world, starting mid-year is actually common for students coming from countries like South Africa and Australia where the academic year actually begins in January. So to my knowledge, most places that accept English speaking international students will accept midyear, as stated in mblochs answer.